# Bash script to auto-kill a process after set amount of time, but also handle user interrupt

Tags: linux, performance, bash, signals

I have a very simple Bash script that runs `top` in batch mode for x seconds, saves the output to a file, and auto-kills `top` after a set amount of time

```
#!/bin/bash
# Runs top under batch mode with renewal period set to $1, saves the data to file $2,  and kills the process after $3 minutes

top -b -d $1 > $2 &

PROC=$!

(sleep $3m; kill $PROC) &
```

The thing is, I also want to be able to handle the killing of the script process, with something like this (I would prefer this over kill )

```
ctrl_c()
    # run if user hits control-c
    {
      echo -en "\n*** Done ***\n"
      cleanup # some cleanup function
      kill $PROC
    }

# trap keyboard interrupt (control-c)
trap ctrl_c SIGINT

while true; do read x; sleep $1; done
```

Is there a neater way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just give `top` a number of iterations to run for:

```
(( total_runtime = $3 * 60 ))
(( iterations = total_runtime / $1 ))
top -b -d $1 -n ${iterations}
```

Comment: Hm... does it use less resources that way? I was actually OK with the first part, but the question was more aimed at a better way to incorporate the second part. Upvoted nonetheless.

Comment: @user991710 Well, this was based on your first sentence requirement "runs top ... and auto-kills top after a set amount of time". This method does not require killing `top`, since it just exits on its own. And since it's not backgrounded, it should still have the controlling terminal and will receive any SIGINTs that get sent, which will terminate `top` as well. If there's other processing you want to do while `top` runs, though, this may not be the right way, and you'll have to do something more complex...